# Google Analytics not collecting ecommerce session data

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-tag-manager

When I go to the Google Analytics [ecommerce shopping behavior](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6014872?hl=en#sba) report for a Magento 2 website, there is not data displayed for:

- Sessions with Product Views
- Sessions with Add to Basket
- Sessions with Check-Out

[image]

I can also see that Enhanced E-commerce Reporting is enabled:

[image]

And that from Stores > Settings > Configuration > Sales > Google API that Google Analytics is set up:
[image]

Not sure what is missing?  Does Google Tag Manager need to be set up, is there a quick way I can check for this on the storefront?

Comment: Do you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

Setting up google tag manager fixed this issue:
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/google-tag-manager.html

As the docs explain you need to Configure Your Google Analytics Account to enable Enable Ecommerce etc.  Then Configure Your Google Tag Manager Account with the recommended Magento GTM settings.

Comment: Do you use Magento Commerce?